# How to handle http POST body

Tags: java, http, post

I have a server that accepts post requests. The post is sent from the Apache libraries.

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
"some code here handles status line"
While (input.ready) {
     line = input.readLine()
     if (line.length() == 0)
    break;
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

The problem is i never actually get the body? I only get the headers?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

1. Read headers with `input.readLine();`
2. Skip 2 empty lines `"\r\n\r\n"`
3. Read body while line.length() != 0.

So the format could look like:

```
Header1\r\n
Header2\r\n
Header3\r\n\r\n
BODY
BODY
BODY...
```

Another option is to use [com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)

Comment: even if i do this
    While (true) {
     line = input.readLine()
     System.out.println(line);}

I only ever get the headers